# How i can use data in jQuery plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery

For example, there is a simple jQuery plugin template

```
(function ($) {
    var defaults = {
        property: 'value'
    },
    methods = {
        init: function (options) {
            return this.each(function() {
                var $this = $(this),
                    data = $this.data('myPlugin');
                if (typeof data === 'undefined') {
                    var settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);
                    $(this).data('photoBoard', {
                        target: $this,
                        settings: settings
                    });
                }
            });
        },
        destroy: function () {
            return this.each(function () {
                var $this = $(this),
                    data = $this.data('myPlugin');
                $this.removeData('myPlugin');
            })
        },

        somethingDo: function () {
            // here i need get data
            var data = $(this).data('myPlugin');

            // something do with data
            // ...

            // and at the end put data back
            $(this).data('myPlugin', data);
        }
    };
    $.fn.myPlugin = function (method) {
        if (methods[method]) {
            return methods[method].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
        } else if (typeof method === 'object' || !method) {
            return methods.init.apply(this, arguments);
        }
        $.error('Метод с именем ' + method + ' не существует для jQuery.myPlugin');
        return this;
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Do not quite understand, if i use the data, i have will in each method do something like this:

```
            // here i need get data
            var data = $(this).data('myPlugin');

            // something do with data
            // ...

            // and at the end put data back
            $(this).data('myPlugin', data);
```

Is this the only way? Perhaps there is another solution? How to use data in plugin methods?

Comment: The way you are using it is right, what more would you like to do?  That or I am missing the point.  You read the data, make changes, and save it again.

Comment: And if the data is not initialized I have to repeat this code in each method. I do not like that there are repeated code. After all, it is incorrectly, do you think?

Comment: Check [here](http://jqueryboilerplate.com/).. where may predefined jQuery plugin templates which is very useful for plugin developement..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you don't have to repeat this code. Just define `data` variable in the outer scope and refer to it in any methods. It will always hold the value you last put into it.

```
(function ($) {
    var defaults = {
        property: 'value'
    },
    data,
    methods = {
        somethingDo: function () {
            // only needed if it wasn't set by methods called previously
            // data = $(this).data('myPlugin');

            // something do with data
            // ...

            // and at the end put data back
            // you could move this call to a helper function as well
            $(this).data('myPlugin', data);
        }
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: So simple, so ingeniously, thanks a lot! How could i not guess?